# 502 bad gateway with Nginx, X-Accel-Redirect and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, x-accel-redirect

I want to allow users to download files from a remote storage but I want to first auth the request through my rails app. I want to hand over the proxying of the remote file to nginx when rails has authenticated the request, to free up the ruby/rails thread.

I have this nginx conf file called proxy_download.conf:

```
   # Proxy download 
   location ~* ^/internal_redirect/(.*?)/(.*) {
     # Do not allow people to mess with this location directly
     # Only internal redirects are allowed
     internal;

     # Location-specific logging
     access_log logs/internal_redirect.access.log combined;
     error_log logs/internal_redirect.error.log warn;

     # Extract download url from the request
     set $download_uri $2;
     set $download_host $1;

     # Compose download url
     set $download_url http://$download_host/$download_uri;

     # Set download request headers
     proxy_set_header Host $download_host;
     proxy_set_header Authorization '';

     # The next two lines could be used if your storage 
     # backend does not support Content-Disposition 
     # headers used to specify file name browsers use 
     # when save content to the disk
     proxy_hide_header Content-Disposition;
     add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$args"';

     # Do not touch local disks when proxying 
     # content to clients
     proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

     # Download the file and send it to client
     proxy_pass $download_url;
   }
```

I import this into the main nginx conf like so:

```
include $ROOT/TO/APP/nginx.conf.d/proxy_download.conf;
```

The app deploys fine and runs properly with this setup.

These are the controller methods to start the download requeset:

```
  def x_accel_url(url, file_name = nil)
    uri = "/internal_redirect/#{url.gsub('http://', '').gsub('https://', '')}"
    uri << "?#{file_name}" if file_name
    return uri
  end

def download
    if auth_is_ok # do some auth logic here
        headers['X-Accel-Redirect'] = x_accel_url('http://domain.com/file.ext')
        render :nothing => true
    end
end
```

When hitting this controller method through the browser, I get the famous nginx error:

```
502 Bad Gateway
```

The error logs only show this:

```
2016/04/22 16:47:27 [error] 11335#0: *150842 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 159.203.238.12, server: domain-removed.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.34:5000/", host: "domain-removed.com
```

What's wrong with my setup? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked error.log? I don't see `resolver`.

Comment: The only error in the logs in this: `2016/04/22 16:47:27 [error] 11335#0: *150842 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 159.203.238.12, server: domain-removed.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.34:5000/", host: "domain-removed.com"` ps I'm not an nginx expert ;-)

Comment: Instead of putting the requested log information in a comment, modify your question and add that information where you would have if you'd originally included it, formatting it for readability of course. Please don't use "Edit" or "Update" to tag it; If you *must* delimit it use `---` to add a horizontal ruler.

Comment: Done :-). Thank you.

Comment: does it works for you @Corstiaan?